# Using set query MySQL - Kohana 3.0

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

im using Kohana 3.0 and MySQL
How to use DB::query(Database::SELECT,'your query'); when used query like this :

```
$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT,
"SET @id_draw=0;
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT a.sender,a.recipient,@id_draw:=@id_draw+1 AS id_draw
            FROM  `gifts` a
            WHERE a.sender = 1499089137
            AND a.sender = (
                SELECT DISTINCT b.recipient
                FROM  `gifts` b
                WHERE b.sender = a.recipient
                AND b.recipient = 1499089137
            )
    GROUP BY a.sender,a.recipient
)x
WHERE x.id_draw = RAND()");
```

**My problem is getting error when using :**

- SET @id_draw=0;
- @id_draw:=@id_draw+1 AS id_draw

Comment: Why GROUP BY??? And don't use a query like this. See JOIN.

Comment: @Strawberry,its just about how to use query like that in kohana  DB::query(Database::SELECT,'your query'); ???

Comment: I think you can include the SET as a SELECT subquery, but this is still a bad query.

Comment: can you give me example ?

Answer (score 0):

Example as requested:

```
 SELECT something
      , another_thing
      , @prev := @curr
      , @curr := amount
      , @rank := CASE WHEN @prev = @curr THEN @rank ELSE @rank+1 END rank
   FROM somewhere
      , (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) defs
  ORDER 
     BY another_thing DESC;
```

Comment: Can you create a view of this query and then just use kohana on the view?